# Node server cannot open specified port

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I am trying to write a program that allows me to communicate with a device using the serial port. To do so, I am using the following code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS1");

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/../.."));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/../../../bower_components/"));



io.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('new connection');

 socket.on('message', function (message) {
//console.log('Position : ' + message); //envoi port ... à la place
//port.on('open', function() {
  port.write(message, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
    }

  });
//});

});
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 8080 port');
});
```

However, the issue here is that the port never seems to open, but the value we are supposed to send is still printed in the console,and the /dev/tty (which represents the console) is opened, but the /dev/ttyS1 do not get opened. The following screenshot is obtained after executing

```
sudo strace -e open,write node server.js
```

[image: Console output]

According to the documentation, the port is supposed to open automatically when we instantiate the SerialPort object.

So, are there any issues in my code or is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: `var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS1");` does call auto open, but it's not synchronous. Pass it a callback to be invoked when the port is actually opened. It'll also have an error object incase there is something that went wrong (which is probably the underlying culprit)

Comment: By adding the « port.on(‘open’,… »  just before the io.on(‘connection’), I don’t have any error but the port.write still doesn’t work. 

In fact, we want that each time we move the joystick on the website, the websocket emit a message with the joystick’s position on the serial port.
This is why our port.write is written after the :
socket.on(‘message’,function(message){